# From current plot $y=f(x)$ get plot $dx/dy$ vs $y$

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I have a plot $y = f(x)$

[image: y = f(x)]

where $y$ is voltage and $x$ is capacity. Now I want get from this graph the $dx/dy$ vs $y$ plot.

How can I get this new graph?

Comment: Do you know the functions or have data points like $(t, V)$ and $(t, C)$? For example, from data, we can use http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Teaching/EngComp/ecl6.pdf.

Comment: It is very strange that on discharge the voltage falls with increasing capacity. That curve should be flipped left to right.  It looks like you have a voltage-time curve on discharge that is plotted with time on the $x$ axis.  Note the capacity is falling on discharge.

Comment: @RossMillikan It was in Spanish, does it make more sense if instead of capacity, it said "capacitance"?

Comment: No, the units seem right for a battery.  mAh is milli-ampere-hours and the division by grams seems to be indicating they are giving the result for some battery chemistry.  A capacitor would have essentially constant capacitance during charge and discharge.  What are you trying to do here if you are guessing about the data?

Comment: @Moo Thanks, for now I only have the graph above, but I can request the data points to my advisor. I believe that with numeric derivatives I can do it. It so complicated. I open to any others suggestions.